# Is CompletableFuture ordering guaranteed when chaining with 'then..' methods is not involved?

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose

```
CompletableFuture<T> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(...);
cf.thenApplyAsync(f)
  .thenApplyAsync(g);

cf.thenApplyAsync(h);
```

By chanining the calls to **f** and **g** we get a guaranteed ordering.
What about **h** ? Do we get any guarentees that **h** will allways be executed after **g** ?

I tried putting **g** to sleep in order to test this and I always see **h** executing after **g** but this is not evidence.
If it is the case that **h** is always executed after **g** where can I find some documentation about this ? I read the CompletionStage, ExecutorService and CompletableFuture docs but I haven't really found any info that would lead me to a conclusion on ordering when chaining like in the case of (g . f) is not involved.

Comment: What do you find unclear in that method's javadoc? *Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed using this stage's default asynchronous execution facility, with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied function.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not in javadocs, it's not guaranteed.  In your case, `h` can easily be executed before `g`.  All it would take for this to happen is for `f` to take a while:

```
cf.thenApplyAsync(i -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("F");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return i;
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}).thenApplyAsync(i -> {
        System.out.println("G");
        return i;
});

cf.thenApplyAsync(i -> {
        System.out.println("H");
        return i;
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried but it seems I should have also waited on the caller thread in order to see the result. Thank you for making me realise my mistake.